# Pass multiple input files to ffmpeg using a single stream in Node

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, stream, node-streams

I'm trying to use ffmpeg to merge multiple video files. Every file has the same encoding, and they just need to be stitched together. The problem I'm having is that I'd like to do this using streams, but ffmpeg only supports one input stream per command.

Since the files have the same encoding, I thought I could merge them into a single stream, and feed it as an input to ffmpeg.

```
const CombinedStream = require("combined-stream")
const ffmpeg = require("fluent-ffmpeg")
const AWS = require("aws-sdk")
const s3 = new AWS.S3()

const merge = ({ videos }) => {
  const combinedStream = CombinedStream.create();

  videos //I take my videos from S3 and merge them
    .map((video => {
      return s3
        .getObject({
          Bucket: "myAWSBucketName",
          Key: video
        })
        .createReadStream()
    }))
    .forEach(stream => {
      combinedStream.append(stream)
    })

  ffmpeg()
    .input(combinedStream)
    .save("/tmp/file.mp4")
}

merge({ videos: ["video1.mp4", "video2.mp4"]})
```

I was hoping ffmpeg could read the files from the single stream and output them together, but I got this error instead:

```
Error: ffmpeg exited with code 1: pipe:0: Invalid data found when processing input
Cannot determine format of input stream 0:0 after EOF
Error marking filters as finished
Conversion failed!
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Regular MP4s have a global index and only one per file, so you can't merge them like that. Look into using the concat demuxer. BTW, ffmpeg supports multiple inputs and multiple outputs per command. However, you're using ffmpeg via a node wrapper which may have its own limitations.

Comment: You need to use the ffmpeg concat demuxer

Comment: did you find the solution with stream?
in my case I need to stream multiples images to create a gif animation
and straggled with this too.